# How to access Axis Type in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change it from based on data to text. how can i write it programmatically?

[image: Where it was]

Answer (score 0):

by changing reverse plot order to false and category minimum solves my problem.

'Hence the name, reverse plot order
`.Axes(xlCategory).ReversePlotOrder = False`

'and keep crosses minimum (this is "between dates" in Excel GUI Format Axis -> Axis Options)
`.Axes(xlCategory).Crosses = xlAxisCrossesMinimum`